# Can I play audio out to both USB and Bluetooth on a MacPro simultaneously?

Tags: audio

I'm running Snow Leopard on a Mac Pro- audio preferences seem to limit audio output to only one port at a time. Is there a way around this? Also the Bluetooth output from the Mac is really weak, is there any way to increase it or make it more effective?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the audio devides: try [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1215) and if it fails try [this](http://osx86.co/f36/audio-tricks-or-more-like-when-aggregate-devices-t1645/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JackOSX](http://jackaudio.org/) it's a powerful and easy app from unix world that allow you to dispatch any input/output into any input/output